# Android Emulator Drained Battery Mbp m1 12.3.1 monterey

Tags: android, emulation, apple-m1

i have development mobile apps with mbp m1 from january 2021 until now jun 2022.

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: dev.polek.adbwifi (1.2.4), com.genymotion.idea (1.0.9), com.github.copilot (1.1.25.1678), com.mallowigi (50.2.0), com.robohorse.robopojogenerator (2.3.5), Dart (212.5744), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (212.5457.16), com.thoughtworks.gauge (212.4746.52), org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.7.0-release-281-AS5457.46), zielu.gittoolbox (212.9.0), io.flutter (68.1.2), com.chrisrm.idea.MaterialThemeUI (6.9.1)
```

but i tired about when i want using android emulator instead of physical device its still on drained my battery ... usually i code with vscode. now i want to test but its still not solved on drained battery when using emulator android.

anyone have solution ?

```
Pixel 4 API Tiramisu
Android API Tiramisu arm64-v8a

RAM 1536 MB
VM Heap 256 MB
Internal Storage 2048 MB
Studio-Managed 2048 MB
```

20 minute drained > 10 percent battery
without android emulator i can coding until 1,5 - 2 days.
but if i want to debug with emulator (only 3-4 hours of my macbook 20% battery).
if my physical device has another task so I can't use it.